# How can I find URL in HTTP response

Tags: http, url, tcp, response

I am trying to create an HTTP parser, and I am interested to know how can I retrieve the URL from HTTP response message **text**. Does every response contain the URL of the page? Do I need to look at some fields in the header for that or just look at the packet's body? Do I need to save information from previous packets (such as location message)?

Answer (score 0):

Requests have URLs, responses are data packets sent back to the client. But if you make an HTTP request, the immediate response will come from the same URL.

Comment: Can I get the URL from the data section in the packet? If I look at the source text of the web page, I see there the URL. If there is no sure way to know the URL from the response then I will need to save all TCP sessions and their last requested URL. Is that right? Last thing - what about sending several GET requests before getting the response? In that case I need to store all the sent URLs